# MongoDB how to find nearest neighbors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am trying to create simple leaderboard using mongo.
I have API build with node.js and express.

For now I have json sorted by user points which looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "_id": "58e543758222ff220d0af481",
    "id": 5,
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Frank",
    "points": 653
    },
    {
    "_id": "58e543758222ff220d0af479",
    "id": 1,
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Bob",
    "points": 321
    },
    {
    "_id": "58e543758222ff220d0af47b",
    "id": 2,
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "John",
    "points": 123
    },
    {
    "_id": "58e543758222ff220d0af47d",
    "id": 3,
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Bravo",
    "points": 34
    },
    {
    "_id": "58e543758222ff220d0af47f",
    "id": 4,
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Bill",
    "points": 12
    }
]
```

I have get request which looks like this:

```
User.find().sort({ points: '-1' }).exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    res.json(users);
});
```

And another get request to find specified id.

```
User.findOne({id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(user);
});
```

I just send id of user and get info about him.
I don't know how to find nearest neighbor of specified id. For example I find user with id: 3 but how to show one user before him and one after him using points.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to query all the users and filter it out using the resultset.

```
User.find().sort({ points: '-1' }).exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err)
        // probably good idea to add return to stop the code from going further
        return res.send(err);

    var nbd = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        // find the user with the given ID
        if (users[i].id == req.params.id) {
            // add user before him
            if (i-1 >= 0) {
                nbd.push(users[i-1]);
            }
            // add user
            nbd.push(users[i]);
            // add user after him
            if (i+1 < users.length) {
                nbd.push(users[i+1]);
            }
            // no need to search any further
            break;
        }
    }

    res.json(nbd);
});
```

Comment: You saved me yesterday and you are doing it again. Thank you :)
Could you tell me if this solution will work for 10000 elements for example? I will send such request once every 2 hours.

Comment: Now, that I don't know. The more I use MongoDB, the more I find how limited it is and end up having to do weird solutions such as this one.

Comment: I just tested this solution on 9276 users and it is working really nice :)

Comment: This has a complexity of Θ(n), which is not good. It will not scale at all. Try looking for users with points at the very end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, just an idea:

```
User.findOne({id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    User.findOne({ "points": { "$gt": user.points } }, { "$orderby": { "points": -1 } }, 
        function(err, user_neigh_greater) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(user_neigh_greater);
    });

    User.findOne({ "points": { "$lt": user.points } }, { "$orderby": { "points": -1 } },
        function(err, user_neigh_lower) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(user_neigh_lower);
    });
});
```

Find the first lower or greater, order by its points. You can use `$gte` or `$lte` if neighbors with equals *points* values are valid.